# Generating non-colliding random numbers from the combination of 2 numbers in a set?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, statistics, bit

I have a set of 64-bit unsigned integers with length >= 2. I pick 2 random integers, `a`, `b` from that set. I apply a deterministic operation to combine `a` and `b` into different 64-bit unsigned integers, `c_1`, `c_2`, `c_3`, etc. I add those `c_ns` to the set. I repeat that process.

What procedure can I use to guarantee that `c` will practically never collide with an existing bitstring on the set, even after millions of steps?

Comment: If you're picking randomly, is there anything that prevents you from picking the very same a and b in your second round that you picked in the first round?

Comment: Does the operation have to be reversible?

Comment: @mhum woops - yes. Sometimes I will generate several `c`s out of the same `a` and `b` pair. Sorry.

Comment: @rici it does not have to be reversible.

Comment: Then why can't it just be a (pseudo-)random number?

Comment: It can, but how can I quickly generate a pseudorandom number deterministically from 2 other numbers? For example, I considered just using "xor" on both numbers, but for some reason eventually I keep getting numbers that are already on the set.

Comment: Doesn't the set object check for a collision?

Comment: @viclib, ah it has to be deterministic. So you will never choose the same `a` and `b`? That wasn't clear from your original question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're generating multiple 64-bit values from a pair of 64-bit numbers, I would suggest that you select two numbers at random, and use them to initialize a 64 bit xorshift random number generator with 128 bits of state. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2B for an example.

However, it's rather difficult to predict the collision probability when you're using multiple random number generators. With a single PRNG, the rule of thumb is that you'll have a 50% chance of a collision after generating the square root of the range. For example, if you were generating 32-bit random numbers, your collision probability reaches 50% after about 70,000 numbers generated. Square root of 2^32 is 65,536.

With a single 64-bit PRNG, you could generate more than a billion random numbers without too much worry about collisions. In your case, you're picking two numbers from a potentially small pool, then initializing a PRNG and generating a relatively small number of values that you add back to the pool. I don't know how to calculate the collision probability in that case.

Note, however, that whatever the probability of collision, the *possibility* of collision always exists. That "one in a billion" chance does in fact occur: on average once every billion times you run the program. You're much better off saving your output numbers in a hash set or other data structure that won't allow you to store duplicates.

Comment: Just found this answer after needing this again, yay! Thanks another time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do without any other given constraints is to use a pseudo-random function that maps two 64-bit integers to a 64-bit integer. Depending on whether the order of `a` and `b` matter for your problem or not (i.e. `(3, 5)` should map to something else than `(5, 3)`) you shouldn't or should sort them before.

The natural choice for a pseudo-random function that maps a larger input to a smaller input is a hash function. You can select any hash function that produces an output of at least 64-bit and truncate it. (My favorite in this case would be [SipHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash) with an arbitrary fixed key, it is fast and has public domain implementations in many languages, but you might just use whatever is available.)

The expected amount of numbers you can generate before you get a collision is determined by the [birthday bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), as you are essentially selecting values at random. The linked article contains a table for the probabilities for 64-bit values. As an example, if you generate about 6 million entries, you have a collision probability of one in a million.

I don't think it is possible to beat this approach in the general case, as you could encode an arbitrary amount of information in the sequence of elements you combine while the amount of information in the output value is fixed to 64-bit. Thus you have to consider collisions, and a random function spreads out the probability evenly among all possible sequences.